# Grub terminal, cannot boot on my installed fedora or windows

Tags: boot, grub

I had windows 11 on my pc and tried to install fedora as a dual boot from a bootable key.
I selected automatic partitioning and toggle the disk encription on, and give a password.
I rebooted and arrived in fedora, typed my password, but it asked it over and over so I reboot on the usb and tried to re-install. Because I had no space left on my disk (everything taken by fedora and windows) I wasn't able to reinstall so I goes in windows and remove the partitions created by fedora, in order to get back with an unallocated partition and booted back on the usb to install fedora, this time without encript the disk. I got this when I reboot:

[image]

And this is what the disk manager shows from fedora trial (using the usb:
[image]

I cannot boot on windows of my installed fedora, but I cann boot on the usb as test mode. What should I do?

Thanks in advance for any tips, help link, ...